# How to retrieve data from PHP in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, backbone.js

I have two MySQL tables called `"spotkania"`(meetings) and `"handlowcy"`(salesmen). I'm aiming at displaying data from both of them in one HTML table.

Here's a simplified version of how the two tables look like:

SPOTKANIA (meetings) is a table with contact details of people with whom the salesmen will arrange meetings. These are the columns:

First name, last name, phone number, and salesman-id.

HANDLOWCY are the salesmen with their contact details:

First name, last name, salesman-id.

What I want to achieve is to select the personal data of every salesman (`"handlowcy"` table) and to assign to him the number of meetings he had based on the salesman-id.

This is what I have in the PHP file so far:

```
require('../misc/database.php');
$db = getConnection();
$statement = $db->prepare('SELECT * from handlowcy left join (SELECT handlowiec (COUNT(handlowiec))as suma FROM `spotkania` WHERE `spotkanie` = 1 GROUP BY handlowiec) as A on A.`handlowiec`=handlowcy.`id`');
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r(json_encode($result));
foreach ($statement as $row) {
    echo json_encode(array("id" => $row['id'], "imie" => $row['imie'], "nazwisko" => $row['nazwisko'], "ulica" => $row['ulica'], "kod" => $row['kod'], "miejscowosc" => $row['miejscowosc'], "rejon" => $row['rejon'], "telefon" => $row['telefon'], "meetings" => $row['?????']));
} 
$statement->closeCursor();
```

and here's the part that's supposed to retrieve the data in Backbone.js view:

```
content += '<tbody><tr><td>' + data[index]["imie"] + '</td><td>' + data[index]["nazwisko"] + '</td><td>' + data[index]["ulica"] + '</td><td>' + data[index]["kod"] + '</td><td>' + data[index]["miejscowosc"] + '</td><td>' + data[index]["rejon"] + '</td><td>' + data[index]["telefon"] + '</td><td class="handlowiec-id">' + data[index]["id"] + '</td><td>' + data[index]['???????'] + '</td></tr></tbody>';
```

So far I can see the contact data for the salesmen, but of course, not the corresponding number of meetings as I have no idea how to approach this.

Comment: why not underscore template its easier and cleaner than printing out manually?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm too much of a newbie to know what's you're talking about. I don't want to make a revolution, just to print out the result in the right cell.

Comment: well since you are using backbone underscore is built-in its not something like rocket science..  http://backbonejs.org/#View-template

Comment: All right, but as I mentioned, I'm a newbie and I didn't know this. I'm trying to make my way around and learning how to deal with problems at work. If it's not rocket science then please help answering the question, I don't see a point of dropping in just to say it's easy and that's it. If the question exists it means it's not easy for the person asking and as far as I'm concerned this site is about providing help.

Comment: well I'm just suggesting for good, GL with your question

Comment: omg, i don't understand how BB connected to your question. If short you do all absolutely against BB ideas. In your case you should make PHP action formating JSON. Then create BB Model which parse this JSON , then create BB View for model rendering  with  underscore template for html markup